# How to translate exception to another using futures in addition to map and flatMap

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

We currently have code like this

```
def somemethod() : Future[Resp] = {
   val responseFuture = service.serveV2(req)
   val nextFuture = responseFuture flatMap {
       //do something on success including call to next async service
   }
   nextFuture
}
```

Of course, the map is being skipped on a timeout but I need to translate that timeout into a proper exception that I can pass up to our web framework to return the correct response code.  How does one do this in scala?

Also of note is that I need to return that future.  Maybe I should be creating a promise and wiring in responseFuture.onFailure into that promise or am I completely off base here?  (I am wondering if there is an easier way or I could try to go down that path).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at `recoverWith` as it allows you to turn a `Throwable` into another `Future` that can either be a failure or a success, depending on how you want to handle it.  This is a bit more flexible than regular `recover` in that you don't always have to return a successful result in your transformation.  So you could do something like this:

```
val newFuture = fut.flatMap(doSomething).recoverWith{
  case t:TimeoutException => Future.failed(new SomeOtherException("timeout!!!"))
}
```

If we get a successful future, the `flatMap` will take effect and the `recoverWith` won't do anything as it's partial function won't match.  If the future is failed with a non-TimeoutException when the `flatMap` won't happen and the `recoverWith` won't do anything either as the PF won't match.  If it fails due to a TimeoutException then the `flatMap` won't happen and the `recoverWith` will kick in and turn it into a failed future wrapping a new `SomeOtherException`

Comment: uhm, this doesn't seem to compile for me as I get no recoverWith method on Future[Response] which is what flatMap returns.  I am not quite following you here.

Comment: scratch that!!!  This project is using it's own Future without a recoverWtih method :(    ugh.